# Applying Conditional Formatting in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a column called Result in my excel sheet. For this column 'K', i have applied Data Validation and now the entire column can take only 2 values i.e Pass, Fail.

Now using conditional formatting i want to apply a rule so that wherever there is a "Fail" in the column, it gets highlighted.

Comment: What have you tried? There is a "Conditional formatting" function in Excel. Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Step:1 - Select column K.
Step-2: I assume you are using Excel 2010 or later. Select Conditional formatting from the Styles section of the Home tab.
Step-3: It opens a sub menu. Select the first option **Highlight Cell Rules**. Opens another sub menu now. Select **Text that contains**
Step-4: A pop up dialog opens. Type the phrase **Fail** in text box and click OK.

Now you have the highlight on Fail as you wanted.

Comment: Why downvote? I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

You can use the conditional formatting on the home tab. Highlight column K and go to conditional formatting - highlight cells rule - text that contains

[image]

Then set your rule for highlighting if the text contains your string:

[image]

Results in highlighted cells -

[image]

Comment: Your are very fast with making screenshots... Good job