# How to copy conditional formatting logic to an entire Excel worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'd like to highlight rows that contain a certain value in a certain cell (Like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/832775/applying-conditional-formatting-in-excel) except highlighting the entire row instead of just the cell). I can get it to work with a single row but I can't figure out a way to apply it to my entire sheet, which has thousands of rows. I've tried several things I found online, but they either don't work in the current version of Excel or require changing the formatting for every row individually (impractical for thousands of rows). I know it's possible because there's conditional formatting for tens of thousands of individual cells in the sheet and there's no way that was all done by hand. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the row you have working.
Grab the corner that has a black dot, using the black cross:
[image: Cross]

Drag it to your other rows:

[image: Cross Drag]

Let go (it'll overwrite your stuff; don't panic):

[image: Overwrite]

Click on the button that appears (or, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>), and select "Fill Formatting Only" from the Autofill Menu:

[image: Autofill Menu]

Now, your conditional formatting formulas have been copied, or the range has expanded, depending.  In this example, the range was expanded:

[image: Conditional Formatting Rules] [image: Conditional Formatting Range]

However, if you have a large sheet, you might not want to manually drag the autofill through multiple scrolls of the scrollbar.  A shortcut to dragging, is to double-click the corner with the black dot when the black cross appears.  It will then automatically gauge where the end of your data lies (usually the next blank cell, but sometimes Excel sees phantom data from deleted rows and such).

Comment: OP could also use `ctl+A` or right click -> select all

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clicking in the top left corner of the sheet? The little grey box with a dark grey arrow in it. Similar to selecting a row except this selects the whole sheet. Kind of like in [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-do-i-apply-conditional-formatting-to-a-whole/10e92384-feaf-46f6-b5ed-c2da8be670a7) Microsoft answer. Or an easier alternative to this and the drag-select answer below is to use `ctl+A` which is the shortcut for select all.

Alternatively you could enable the [developer tab](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/show-the-developer-tab-e1192344-5e56-4d45-931b-e5fd9bea2d45) and then use VBA. You could then select 'Record Macro' and set the [conditional formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.formatconditions.add) for a single cell. Open that macro and just change the cell selection to suit.

Or write your own with something like the following:

```
Sub conditionalFormat()
    with ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.FormatConditions__
        .Add(xlCellValue, xlGreater, "=$a$1") 
    With .Borders 
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous 
        .Weight = xlThin 
        .ColorIndex = 6 
    End With 
    With .Font 
        .Bold = True 
        .ColorIndex = 3 
    End With 
    End With

End Sub
```